# Docker registry notifications multiple push

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm using my own private Docker registry and I would like to send Slack notifications when a new image is pushed.

I used Huginn to catch registry webhook notifications and send to Slack. My issue is that Docker registry send multiple notifications when an image is pushed with same informations:

`"action": "push"`

How can I send only one notification from docker registry? Or differenciate the last notification?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution!

I check only action == push and mediaType == application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json

Answer (score 1):

#### same issue, but i fixed:

`timeout` and `backoff` default is `ns` not `ms`

#### with my config:

`notifications:
  endpoints:
    - name: webhook
      disabled: false
      url: http://example.com
      timeout: 3000ms
      threshold: 5
      backoff: 1S`

Answer (score 0):

Docker registry sends multiple requests due to several reasons.

1. for some actions there are multiple request made **at the same time** but with different request methods, e.g. HEAD and then GET for action `pull`, so you should always specify the metod (e.g. POST for `push`);
2. there are two media types used: newer `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` and legacy `application/octet-stream`. You can ignore the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when setting up notifications to trigger watchtower to upgrade docker images.

My problem was that when watchtower got the event it makes a pull to look for new images. That event triggered a new notification which created a loop.

I added ignoreMediatypes and ignore the pull action which worked for me.

```
notifications:
  endpoints:
    - name: watchtower
      url: ....
      headers:
        Authorization: [Bearer ...]
      timeout: 500ms
      threshold: 5
      backoff: 10s
      ignoredmediatypes:
        - application/octet-stream
      ignore:
        mediaType:
          - application/octet-stream
        actions:
          - pull
```